# slick setPosition doesnt work

Tags: slick.js

I've a slider of thumbs and a Slick slider in a layer on top , hidden through css with display:none. On click event I've called setPosition but it doesnt work(

```
<div id="slider" style="display:none">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="img-item">
        <a href="#"><img src="/media/img/example-vip5.png" alt="" width="132px"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="img-item">
         <a href="#"><img src="/media/img/example-vip1.png" alt="" width="132px"></a>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="img-item"><a href="#">
            <img src="/media/img/example-vip2.png" alt="" width="132px">
        </a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="show-slider"></a>

$('.show-slider').click(function(){
    $('#slider').show()
    $('#slider').get(0).slick.setPosition();
})
```

error: Cannot read property 'setPosition' of null

Comment: What exactly happens when you call setPosition?  Do you get an error? You can edit your question to add this information.  Someone will be more likely able to help you if you do.

Comment: error: Cannot read property 'setPosition' of null

Comment: `$('#slider').get` returns native DOM element; you're looking for `$('#slider').eq`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#slider').slick('setPosition');
```

Maybe, you have to use the class of the slick element instead of the ID#slider

```
$('.slick-slider').slick('setPosition');
```

Source:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine in using `visibility:none`, I suggest you to use this. But you need to position this using `CSS` position   properties.

```
<div id="slider" style="visibility:hidden">
```

If you use this your `div` will retain height and width in DOM and also while initiating slick. You can make visible on your wish.

```
$('.show-slider').click(function(){$('#slider').css("visibility","visible");});
```

No need to use slick set position.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 tabs. You need to trigger the position change on the tab shown event.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('.yourcarousel').slick('setPosition');
});
```